# Django rest upload and read excel file

Tags: excel, angular, django-rest-framework

I am new to django-rest and want to ask, if there is a simple way to upload an xlsx file and read the data from it with django rest and angular2. I would like to have the possibility to read the file from specific row.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify: does your xlsx file map to multiple items you have a model for.  Assuming that's the case, you probably want to look at something like django-excel to handle the translating

Comment: The main problem is, that I have several types of xlsx files, which map to one model, so I must do it manualy. On some files the header is on row 20  with the data below and on some files is the header on row 1 with data below. The thing I want to ask for is, how to upload the file and then read the requested data manualy from it. Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem with pyexcel